# Correct event binding in JavaScript view? Different this binding with XML views

Tags: sapui5

In the SAPUI5 Developers Guide I found this note on handling events:

> Handling Events in XML Views. Event handlers are used as attributes. The attribute name is the event name, such as "press" for a button, and the attribute value as event handler name. The event handler must be defined as a  function in the view's controller. To attach an event handler in a XML view, insert the following declaration: ... `<Button text="Press Me" press="doSomething"/>` ... The method `controller.doSomething()` is executed when the button is pressed.

In my XML view, I can translate this into:

```
<Select change="doSomething">
```

When the value for the select is changed, the `controller.selectOnChange` function is called, with the *«this argument bound to the controller itself»*. When I bind this event handler in a JavaScript View, however, the *«this argument is bound to the select element»*.

I assume that this translates into the following code for my JavaScript view:

```js
new sap.m.Select({ change : oController.doSomething })
```

Am I binding the event handler the wrong way?

Answer (score 10):

In JS views, when you specify a handler like this:

```js
new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Press Me",
    press: oController.myHandler
})
```

then `this` is bound to the control itself in the handler.

But there's another way to specify the handler, like this:

```js
new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Press Me",
    press: [oController.myHandler, oController]
})
```

where the second element in the array becomes what `this` is bound to.

I've added [an example with a JS view and controller to sapui5bin's `SinglePageExamples`](https://github.com/qmacro/sapui5bin/blob/master/SinglePageExamples/HandlerContext.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you call it through the XML-View or HTML-View the context of this Event-Method is the controller. In JS-View the context is the control itself. That means you have to call it with `jQuery.proxy()` like this:

```js
new sap.m.Select({ change : jQuery.proxy(oController.doSomething, oController) })
```

In this way the `oController` is your method-context. But I think, you can also use the method `addEventDelegate()`. See SAPUI5-doc for more information: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#addEventDelegate